# C++ Standard Library algorithms readability

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I used to write code in a way that it could be read as plain English.

Can someone give a clue how it is better to read the code below in these terms?

My problem is that the code below reads as “erase all unique elements” while it does quite opposite.

This is not a suggestion to rework STL and ranges somehow, I just curious about some trick in considering/treating `std::unique` (and some other methods) in this context to make this text less counter-intuitive.

In absence of “not” in the code below (which could help to read as "not unique" or "except unique") what would be the best way to read this code?

```
std::vector<T> v = …;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

Ranges version is not better in these terms:

```
std::vector<T> v = …;
std::ranges::sort(v);
v.erase(std::ranges::unique(v), v.end());
```

Comment: `auto start_of_duplicates = ...; std::erase(start_of_duplicates, v.end())`?

Comment: "erase everything except unique elements"?

Comment: Damir: Didn't yesterdays discussion about the STL tag make you want to avoid that tag when you mean the C++ Standard Library? :) From [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library): _"The STL and the C++ Standard Library are two distinct entities"_

Comment: @Botje, thank you, it helps a bit, but the problem moves to line: `auto start_of_duplicates = std::unique(...);` which is just slightly better, since rely on very vague side effect (although, well document) of the `std::unique` algorithm. With this I mean that when I call to std::unique I mainly expect to stay with unique elements and only as a side effect expect to have repeated elements after the returned iterator **as documented behaviour**. If I were the author of std::unique, I wouldn't set such a constraint on my algorithm, so as a user I don't expect it subconsciously as given.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, we need to have some motivation to put word "except" here (updated the question, stressing it). We can't put it here and there just by wish, since it reverses the meaning. Here we don't have any kind of "not" in the code, so no "hook" to use "except" here. This is the basis of my question.

Comment: The "very vague side effect" is a deliberate choice to make the process as efficient as possible and in-place. Feel free to make a `my::unique(some_container)` function that abstracts the lines you pasted if it makes your code clearer.

Comment: erase all elements starting from the first that is not unique after moving the non uniques to the end of the vector, till the end of the vector.  The "not unique" is from what `std::unique` returns. Generally functions do something and return something, and often both cannot be expressed in a single verb or noun. This isnt a feature of STL

Comment: `std::erase(iterator, iterator)` doesn't exist. Did you mean `v.erase(iterator, iterator)`?

Comment: Uh, the obvious way "write a function with a name you think is better"? But really, this is an instance of erase-remove idiom that most C++ programmers should be familiar with. And if they aren't, they look up what `unique` does and what `erase` does.

Comment: C++ is not Fortran. One of Fortran's historical advocacies is that it could be, if one twisted their head sufficiently to the side, read like English. This was not the case with C++.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I am lost again and I will be truly thankful if you help me again to see and cement the difference. In which way the first code snippet doesn't belong to STL? All the containers and algorithms from it belong to STL. Where am I wrong in this case?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Can you show me a link to the STL implementation or documentation of `std::erase`? That algorithm does not exist in the C++ Standard Library (which is what most people use since C++98) but perhaps it existed in STL. If the difference between STL and the C++ Standard Library isn't clear, please check the wiki I linked to.

Comment: @DamirTenishev [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) is an ancient library that existed before C++ was even standardised. It was largely baked into C++ standard library, so people kept using the name, but these are not the same. There's zero reason to mention STL nowadays, unless you for some reason are using that particular library instead of C++ standard library.

Comment: @Botje, this is more about reading than writing. The question comes when I read code written by somebody else. I see where you coming from with the deliberate choice, but for me this verges overloading function's responsibility, although I get the point of "in-place". This makes sense, of course.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, thank you. I have to agree here. The only concern for me here is this naming is really correct. For example, wouldn't `separate_unique` be more intuitive in this case, stressing that we not only keep unique, but get both, separating them by returned iterator?

Comment: what is "intuitive" is purely subjective. For me c++ is the main language, I am used to `std::unqiue` and I suppose I would need time to adjust to whatever name a different language chose for the same algorithm. Cppref states "Eliminates all except the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range. " and imho that fits perfecltly with `unique`. The resulting range has only unique elements. Makes sense

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thank you for catching this, I messed with freestanding [std::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) function that work on containers and simplify things considerably but intended to replace erase-remove idiom so this code should have had another form. Let's stay with std::vector::erase for simplicity.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, this is more about reading other's code and about statement "if to understand the system one need to read documentation, the system is poorly designed". I read most of code without digging into details of functions implementation or documentation. Of course, this is based on background knowledge, but I find this case counter-intuitive. Well, people persuaded me that this is opinion-based holy war.

Comment: c++ is full of bad names. `std::move` doesnt move anything is imho the best example. Its a relatively new addition to the lanuguage, yet they didnt manage to find a better name. Once you start using 3rd party libraries it gets only worse. I think you have to give up your premise and accept that intuition and good naming cannot possibly replace reading documentation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, does this mean that we shouldn't pursuit the goal to make the code as readable as possible and avoid traps where one need to read documentation instead of reading the code?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, if 2 functions out of 3 and one container belong to STL and only one doesn't (now after update, all belong to STL),  is this is the case to avoid using STL tag? I mean, with 1 container and 2 functions this is already STL-related. Nevertheless, *463035818_is_not_an_ai* and others have persuaded me that this question is related to programming basics rather than STL, ranges or even C++. So, I am removing at least STL tag. Considering replacing all tags or closing the question, at all.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Let me turn that around: What implementation are you using? Are you using whatever C++ Standard Library that comes with that implementation or have you replaced that with the STL?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, what do you mean? I use `std::vector::erase` at the moment when I work with STL and `std::ranges::erase` when I work with ranges. Is that what you asking?

Comment: What compiler do you use? What version of that compiler?

Comment: "we not only keep unique, but get both, separating them by returned iterator" except that isn't what `std::unique` does. It keeps the unique elements, and leaves the remaining elements in a moved-from state

Comment: @DamirTenishev I'll break this down for you.  The STL, is the standard template library, created back in the 90's to be a library for the then non-standardized C++.  Then, in 1998, when C++ was formally standardized they added to the C++ standard the Stand Library.  That is the the library you are using, not the STL.  The STL ended a long time ago and now we just have the C++ Standard Library.  Pretty much all uses of saying "I'm using the STL" are actually wrong and they are using the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: `std::vector::erase` is not STL, its the c++ standard library. Why keep using the term STL?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I have to agree with your both last statements. The only holy war question I have on the table, then. Do you really think that "RTFM" and "many bad examples of bad code" gives enough excuse for unreadable code? My stand is that if code needs documentation, the design is bad and if code needs comments, it is very tricky case caused by language (or other API) incompleteness or problem in code. I read tons of unreadable code, but at the same time I read some large systems where C++ code is well-structures and very easy to read and understand.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Visual Studio 2022, latest version.

Comment: Yes, the C++ Stand Library was influenced by the STL but they are not the same,  It is like saying C++ is just C with classes since it came from C, which greatly misses out on the difference between C and C++.

Comment: @DamirTenishev _"Visual Studio 2022, latest version"_ - Ok, that does not contain the STL. It contains an implementation of the C++ Standard Library. Unless you explicitly installed the STL and made it work in VS2022, you don't have the STL available to you and tagging questions with STL just makes it confusing.

Comment: @Caleth, it seems that it comes to personal understanding of wording (or my lack of understanding in this particular case). I see the difference, but I don't see enough difference to reflect it in a short consistent algorithm name. Could you please, give a clue on it?

Comment: `v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());` is very readable to me. There's nothing unreadable about it. C++ is not English, English is not C++. One cannot expect to read C++ using just plain English words any more than one can expect to read something in French, also using plain English words.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thank you, it helps. In this case, if I use in my questions STL partially (like in this example std::vector and std::sort), why shouldn't/mustn't I use STL tag? Let's forget for the moment that, as people here helped me understand, the question is not related to STL, ranges or C++ and related to algorithm basics. If not so, are you saying that tag should be set only in case I address STL specifics, not just use it? Another question, with this long STL story, what is the best place to see what is a part of STL and what is not while asking next questions?

Comment: I didnt give "excuses for bad code". If you ponder long enough about any name you can find a better one, but so what? We all try to give good names, sometimes it agrees with readers of our code think sometimes not.

Comment: "My stand is that if code needs documentation, the design is bad " I strongly disagree.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thank you so much. This finally got me understanding this. So, would it be correct wording that current std::vector, std::sort, etc. on Visual Studio, at least, is not a part of STL, but a part of Standard C++ Library which has nothing to do with STL and just inherits some stuff from it in terms of name, ideology, etc.?

Comment: There isn't a short consistent algorithm name other than `unique`. It modifies a range in-place, such that there are no consecutive equal elements between it's first parameter and it's result. Algorithms cannot contain all their nuance in their names

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, thank you, I get both the points. Let me prepare better on latter subject and open a discussion on that in more appropriate place. Again, I don't argue, I just want to understand, but this would be off-topic here.

Comment: consider that `std::unique` is probably the result of many clever coders having long discussions on what the best name would be and thats what they came up with. Frankly, one can almost get the impression you think they choose a bad name on purpose.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Your last comment about STL is correct, and it's not just MSVC. GCC and Clang today also have nothing to do with STL. STL is an **ancient** library from stone ages.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, yes, two programmers is always at least three opinions. That's exactly why I raised the question, to see from others' eyes.

Comment: @DamirTenishev You are not using the STL.  The STL is a special library that you have to go out and get.  You are using the built in C++ Standard Library your compiler provided so you saying you are using the STL is incorrect.  You are using a Library that has it's roots in the STL but it is not the STL.

Comment: @DamirTenishev you are not the only one who messes up `v.erase` and `std::erase`. I have known about 'erase-remove idiom' for years, but each time I need to use it, I have to look up cppreference and see which of `remove` and `erase` is a member and which is a free function. They are easily confused and I find impossible to keep in memory. This is the kind of interface that is not easy to use, and the argument about efficiency over usability is questionable at best in the language that relies on heavy optimizations and 'as-if' principle.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik As for efficiency I'm surprised that `remove`/`remove_if`/`erase`/`erase_if` are all _stable_ algorithms and that no "unstable" versions exist since they have the potential of being faster. I started making a matching set of such `unstable_*` algorithms but only finished those I needed myself at the time. They are indeed faster than their stable counterparts in many cases.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the problem is in the interface: it should be convenient for 95% cases and customizable for the rest. But because it is made backwards, everyone has to adhere to erase-remove idiom 95% of the time and  maaaybe 5% have some use of the range after the returned end iterator. 95% of erase is to "get rid of" - it should be a single action

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Yes. That usecase is so common that `std::erase`/`std::erase_if` was added for the containers where it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very literal transliteration into English would be:

"Sort v, so the next step has the expected result. From v, erase between the result of unique of v and the end of v"

Which could be slightly massaged into

"Erase everything after the unique elements"

Comment: btw, actually `std::unique` is even more quirky than has been discussed so far. It only moves repeating *consecutive* elements to the back. You can end up with non unique elements in the resulting range (just not consecutive). You are expected to sort the range before

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai edited the long form part to make clear sort is necessary

Comment: I like the wording "erase between *the result* of unique". People in comments did their best to explain this to me, but only this exact short wording made it "fire" for me. Indeed, `erase` is interested in result, not in what the algorithm actually does and this is the clue; not so obvious and readable, but good enough clue to refer to documentation on the returned value. Now all wrapped out to make the code at least understandable for me. Thanks.